# ht access issue, with examples

Tags: php, .htaccess

My end goal is to have something like this.

**127.0.0.1/site/search/search-term**

Rather than,

**127.0.0.1/site/search.php?term=**

I have tried two pieces of code, first being.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../search.php?term=$1
```

And i put this inside a folder called /search. The HTACCESS works perfectly but the css gets messed up for my website, it just shows everything as plain text without any styling.

Secondly i tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /search/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../search.php?term=$1
```

And put that in 127.0.0.1/site/ root. But when i tried 127.0.0.1/site/search/searchterm I get a 404.

Can anyone see where i am going wrong? I am guessing the first option is the best one to work towards getting fixed as it is so close, i look through the source of the page i receive after using the vainty url and i think it might be something to do with how im linking the style sheet? It works if i put the full address in for the link (127.0.0.1/site/main.css) But then all it fails on all my jquery includes etc. Is it wise to just put the full address in when ever i want to use vanity urls?

Comment: You're htaccess does another thing: your working directory will be: `127.0.0.1/term`

Comment: Why is that? as far as  i know the rewritebase doesn't have to be the same as the get variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you're using absolute paths in CSS, JS and images files. That means path to these resources should either start with a slash `/` or `http://`. If you don't already have it then please make necessary code changes. Once that is done use following .htaccess in `$DOCUMENT_ROOT` (**not in `$DOCUMENT_ROOT/site`**):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^site/search/(.+)/?$ site/search.php?term=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

**EDIT:** As per your comments here is the code to make a URI in lowercase:

First add this line in  section OR at the end of your httpd.conf file:

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
```

Then have your rules like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^site/search/(.+)/?$ site/search.php?term=${lc:$1] [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. One last thing, is there a way to make it so that everything that is entered is lowercase? Not important but would like to know :) Will accept answer after your reply.

Comment: There is a way to make all URIs lowercase but it involves making a small change in httpd.conf as well. Please check in the EDIT section of my answer.